# Stdout of process not redirected properly via dll injection

Tags: c, winapi, stdout, dll-injection

I'm injecting a C dll (as a thread) into a running console process, and trying to redirect its stdout to a file. My dll also writes to the console via `wprintf`.

As a simple redirection test I made the dll call `TestRedirect` at the start:

```
FILE *file = NULL;
BOOL WINAPI Test1(void *param);

void TestRedirect()
{
    file = freopen("C:\\temp\\test1.txt", "w", stdout);
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, Test1, (void*)file, NULL, 0, NULL);
}

BOOL WINAPI Test1(void *param)
{
    FILE *file = (FILE*)param;
    while (1)
    {
        wprintf(L"Test1\n");
        fflush(file);
        Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Every time my dll writes to stdout via `wprintf`, regardless of the thread, the text appears in the file. However, my test console program (also a C program) doesn't write to the file. All the console program does is call `wprintf` every second to print something. When my dll is injected in the process, the exe's text stops appearing in the console window but doesn't get written to the file. Same if I try it on other programs, e.g. ping.exe.

However if I put the same code directly into my test console program and make that program call `TestRedirect`, then the program's output is written to the file (without injecting the dll).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The CRT in one module doesn't know anything about the CRT in another module, so redirecting CRT file handles in a DLL won't have the effect you are looking for. `SetStdHandle` might get you what you want.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I tried `SetStdHandle` and it had zero effect (even though the function didn't fail) - both the program and the dll kept writing to the console.

Comment: It definitely can't work unless the exact same CRT is dynamically linked into both modules; Process Explorer can show you whether you have a single CRT or two CRTs loaded.  But I don't know how `freopen` and `printf` interact with threads, either.  What happens if you put the `freopen` call into the main application, but have it run in a different thread once the rest of the program is already up and running?

Comment: Right, I see what you're saying. I got it to work with my program after I changed both the exe and dll runtime linking from static to dynamic. Unfortunately it has to work with programs I haven't written, with any version of the runtime. I'll look into it further and post an answer if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by making the injected dll call `FreeConsole` and then `AttachConsole`, passing in the PID of the process with the console where I wanted the output to be redirected to.

(I know the question mentioned redirecting it to a file, but that was really just for testing purposes as an ostensibly easier thing to do; ultimately, I wanted it to be redirected to a console. At the end of the day, I can make my own console redirect its stdout (which it receives from the "remote" process) to a file if I want, which should still satisfy the actual question.)